# Python re.split: how to preserve patten

Tags: python

In python codes are:

```
list = "a123,145B,12"
re.split("[a-zA-Z_]",list)
```

Result:

```
['', '123,145', ',12']
```

How can I preserve characters, so the result will be:

```
['a','123,145','B',',12']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capture group :

```
>>> re.split("([a-zA-Z_])",li)
['', 'a', '123,145', 'B', ',12']
```

And for get ride of empty string you can use `filter` built-in function  :

```
>>> filter(bool,re.split("([a-zA-Z_])",li))
['a', '123,145', 'B', ',12']
```

Comment: By the way, is there any method to get rid of the first null character''?